# How to configure local server in IIS to host many websites

Tags: iis

I am trying to serve various websites using one local host using IIS. For example, I am trying to have my server address 'XYZ' host two different applications only separated by a '/'. So for application 1 I would host it as 'XYZ/1' and for application 2 I would host it as 'XYZ/2'.

I have already tried using binding methods and application pools to no avail.

Thank you

Comment: What you're looking for is called [Virtual Applications](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/iis/get-started/planning-your-iis-architecture/understanding-sites-applications-and-virtual-directories-on-iis).

Comment: Thank you very much mason. That helped.